# Why interstellar space travellers would need to decelerate their ship?

Tags: interstellar-travel

In many sci-fi novels I have read, the interstellar travelers had their ship half the way accelerate, then half the way decelerate. I wonder why this is the chosen approach? Would not it be better to accelerate all the way, then leave the ship for small landing module(s) and decelerate them while allowing the interstellar ship to go away from the star system? Maybe, even eject the landing modules from the mother ship in opposite direction.

**Clarification:** I meant unidirectional travel aimed at colonization of new worlds.